# VBScript does not oFS.FileExists a file in oFS.CreateFolder

Tags: vbscript, windows-10, file-exists, create-directory

I'm having a strange problem with VBScript. I'd like to implement some other code with a following test:

**If there is a file named like [that] in the [folder], do not copy it into the [folder].**

Thing is, I found a strange relation in oFS.FileExists, I'm able to use it in a manually created folder, as long as I manually copy and paste a file into it. Then oFS.FileExists works like a charm.

```
Dim oFS
Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

filestr = "C:\where\file\is\file.file"

If (oFS.FileExists(filestr)) Then
  WScript.Echo("File exists!")
  WScript.Quit()
Else
  WScript.Echo("File does not exist!")
End If
```

But it's not exactly my point. I'd like to test if a file is already in the desired folder, and such folder will be generated automatically with oFS.CreateFolder. But when it comes to testing an automatically generated folder, it's a different story.

```
Dim oFS
Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

oFS.CreateFolder(destination & objFoldername)
```

Initially I thought it might be something wrong with the file I'm looking for. I moved it to some other place and the oFS.FileExists found it. So I figured it might be the case of the folder itself. I can see the folder is a Read Only folder. I tested it in other manually created Read Only folder, also found it.
Finally I manually created the folder exactly like oFS.CreateFolder would do it, pasted manually a file into it and... it also found a file just fine.

**As I witnessed, every test I conduct in a generated folder is failed, but done in a manually created one, pass.**

Remarkable!

**Had anyone such a case? Do you know why oFS.FileExists puts a blind eye on something created itself?**

I'm using 64-bit Windows 10 Home, and I wrote both scrips in Visual Studio Code if that would be relevant.

Cheers guys, I can't be the first one.

## EDIT for leeharvey1

Thank you leeharvey1 that you took a minute to have a look at this. This is the code that creates the directories:

```
Dim oFS, oFile, objShell, objFolder, sFolderPathspec, destination, file
Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sFolderPathspec = "C:\folder\where\files\are\"
Set objShell = CreateObject ("Shell.Application")
destination = "C:\folder\where\new\folders\with\files\are\intended\to\be\"
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(sFolderPathspec)


For Each file In objFolder.Items    
    name = file.Name
    wykonano = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(file, 12)
    If wykonano = "" Then
        wykonano = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(file, 3) 
    End If
    arr = Split(wykonano, " ") 
    brr = Split(arr(0), "-")
    rok = brr(0)
    miesiac = brr(1)
    objFoldername = rok & "-" & miesiac
    
    If CStr(oFS.FolderExists(destination & objFoldername)) >< "Prawda" Then
        oFS.CreateFolder(destination & objFoldername)
    End If

    newdestination = destination & objFoldername & "\" & name
    
    oFS.CopyFile sFolderPathspec & name, newdestination, False
     
Next
```

The whole testing for file existence started because I could not have the following to run:

```
oFS.CopyFile sFolderPathspec & name, newdestination, False
```

I would love it to copy but not overwrite. False, is however syntax correct, opposing to "Fałsz" (which would be correct in my Windows language). But the code crashes as soon as it hits the file that is already in the destination folder. Maybe should I have some kind of code which will let the sequence of code continue over the crashes caused by already existing files? (Like Python has)

So it took me to the following problem of testing for existence.

I figured I'll use the following method of the Files collection. As mentioned above, I get fails every time I conduct a test in generated folder, but done in a manually created one, pass.

That's the code (so far in a different VBScript file):

```
filestr = "C:\where\file\is\file.file"

Dim oFS
Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If oFS.FileExists(filestr) Then
    MsgBox("Jest plik")
Else
    MsgBox("Nie ma pliku")
End If

Function FileExists(FilePath)
  Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  If oFS.FileExists(FilePath) Then
    FileExists=CBool(1)
  Else
    FileExists=CBool(0)
  End If
End Function

If FileExists(filestr) Then
  WScript.Echo "Does Exist"
Else
  WScript.Echo "Does not exist"
End If

If (oFS.FileExists(filestr)) Then
  WScript.Echo("File exists!")
  WScript.Quit()
Else
  WScript.Echo("File does not exist!")
End If
```

So, there are some details you wanted to know:

- No, I am not working against a network shared file. It's all locally on my PC's ssd.
- Have you tried disabling your anti-virus? No, if I'll need to do so in order to use it, I don't need the code.
- I think I need to look for a file not for a folder, there is some kind of problem to locate the file. Do you think there could be also a problem to locate the folder itself?
- Check folder Owner. Well, as far as I can see in Windows folder properties, it looks and have just the same settings as any other folder over there.

Thanks again leeharvey1 for your time!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Can you post your minimally complete test code that can reproduce this problem?  Is your script running in a different account context (check folder Owner)?  Are you working against a network file share (timing/delays)?  Have you tried disabling your anti-virus?  FYI, CreateFolder() returns a Folder object, so perhaps saving it to a variable for the duration of your script might help.  Also, be careful not to call FileExists() for folders; instead, use FolderExists().